# GPIO pin being set to input upon exiting program

Tags: gpio, python, rpi.gpio

I have this code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

    try:
            GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
            GPIO.setup(3, GPIO.OUT)
            GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)
            GPIO.output(12, GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(3, GPIO.HIGH)
            time.sleep(7.5)
            GPIO.output(12, GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(3, GPIO.LOW)
    except:
            GPIO.cleanup()
    finally:
            GPIO.cleanup()
```

When the program exits, the LED connected to pin 3, (along with a 220 ohm resistor) stays on a little bit. Running `gpio readall` reveals that the pin has been set to IN. (Which is what I suspect is causing the issue; as running `gpio export 2 out` fixes the problem).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: A clear picture or diagram of your circuit could be useful...

Comment: @DarthVader Sure! It's about as simple as possible. GPIO pin on the Pi > LED > 220ohm resistor > GND.

Comment: GPIO.cleanup resets all pins to their default state (INPUT). If you don't call it, the pins will be left in whatever state you set them (but RPi.GPIO will whinge with a warning next time you run the script)

Comment: @DaveJones then is it in this case acceptable to not call GPIO.cleanup? Or is there something I can do to my circuit to prevent the LED from glowing when the pin is put into input mode? Or another solution I'm not thinking of?

Comment: Why don't you explicitly set the GPIO output pin driving the LED so it is off before you call the cleanup?

Comment: Any reason why you can't move the cleanup outside the try/except, then no need for the finally statement.

Comment: @barny is correct there's no point repeating stuff in except&finally (the finally will execute no matter what). Still, as mentioned you need to remove that in order to preserve the state of the GPIOs upon exit. It is indeed acceptable to skip cleanup (it's never absolutely required - only if you want to be certain the GPIOs are all back to input). As to why it glows faintly, one of your pins is probably GPIO2/3 (in BCM numbering) which have weak hardware pull-ups attached for I2C

Comment: Oh your 'on a little bit' means 'faintly glowing'. I had read 'little bit' as 'short time'. if you want the LED to stay on why not just leave your program running?